# Store each DataTable Column in string var

Tags: c#

I want to store each Datatable Column in a string variable so that i can pass all these parameters to my stored procedure.
This will go on for each row in DataTable

```
DataTable dtOutput;
dtOutput= Generix.getFeedData(1,ref Connection);
foreach (DataRow drOutput in dtOutput.Rows)
{
    Console.Write("IST: ");
    foreach (DataColumn dcOutput in dtOutput.Columns)
    {
        Console.Write(Convert.ToString(drOutput[dcOutput]) + "\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Above Code should Print Each Column and a `"\t"` as separator and new row on new line.My DataTable Contains 4 Columns

My DataTable Prints in Following Way:

```
ATM         Message

ABC001      Hello
ABC002      SAGAR
```

Now i want in following way:

```
string sAtm;// Should Print ABC001
string sMsg;//Should Print Hello
```

For Next Row Value in `sAtm` will be `ABC002`

Comment: If that's what your code "should" print, what is it currently printing?  This appears to be valid code at first glance...

Comment: Storing Each Printed in Column in String Variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, you could use Linq to get all params as string.

Pick out what you need:

```
var allAsString = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select((r, ri) => new
    {
        Row = r,
        RowNumber = ri,
        Fields = r.ItemArray.Select((f, i) => new 
        {
            Col = table.Columns[i],
            FieldText = string.Format("{0}", f)
        })
    });
```

So if you for example want to iterate all rows and get specific fields:

```
foreach (var rowInfo in allAsString)
{
    string sAtm = rowInfo.Fields.First(f => f.Col.ColumnName == "ATM").FieldText;
    string sMsg = rowInfo.Fields.First(f => f.Col.ColumnName == "Message").FieldText; 
}
```

Remember to add `using system.Linq;`.

---

**Edit**: If you instead want to save the whole DataTable in one string:

```
String strTable = String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine, 
        table.AsEnumerable().Select(r => String.Join("\t", r.ItemArray)));
```

Comment: & In which string Data Column in Being Stored ?

Comment: This will store each column in one string variable at a time..i want all the columns in one row to stored in diff string variables.

Comment: @SagarDumbre: Edited my answer if you just want one string with all fields of all rows. If you instead want all fields of all rows in a different variable use my first approach which creates an `IEnumerable<anonymous type>`.

Comment: @SagarDumbre: Edited my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
DataTable dtOutput = Generix.getFeedData(1,ref Connection);

foreach (DataRow drOutput in dtOutput.Rows)
{
    sb.Append("IST: ");
    foreach (DataColumn dcOutput in dtOutput.Columns)
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(drOutput[dcOutput]) + "\t");
    }
    sb.AppendLine();
}
```

Your data will then be stored in `sb` so just convert to a string when passing to your stored procedure `sb.ToString()`.

Comment: cant i store each column value to diff string for one particular row.and next row all previous string values should get deleted

Comment: @SagarDumbre well, yes you could. Does this mean you're going to be calling your stored procedure on each iteration of `dtOutput.Rows`?