# Datatable column into a string with string.join

Tags: string, join, datatable

I have a datatable that contains a single column. I want to join all the rows in this datatable in to a single string with string.join

I used the following but it gives me the error best overloaded method for string.join(string, string[]) has some invalid arguments.

```
 string s = string.Join(", ", ds.Tables[1].Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(r => r[0].ToString()));
```

Can someone help me with writing it correct?

I was referring to the following to get that code:
[Store each DataTable Column in string var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032675/store-each-datatable-column-in-string-var)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code seams correct.

If you have a datatable with one column like this:

```
Test
====
123
456
```

And apply your code, you will get the string "123, 456"

```
// Init datatable
var dt = new DataTable();            
dt.Columns.Add("Test");
dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow()["Test"] = "123");
dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow()["Test"] = "456");

// Join columns
string s = string.Join(", ", dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(r => r[0].ToString()));
```